# Junit test not working correctly with Math.pow

Tags: java, testing, junit

It's might be a trivial question as I'm just a beginner in programming. 
The task is to write a code that raises array's elements to a third power for the following Junit test case:

```
@Test
    public void testCubeArray() {
        FirstSteps firstSteps = new FirstSteps();
        int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 0};
        firstSteps.cube(array1);
        int[] arrayResult1 = {1, 8, 27, 0};
        assertArrayEquals(arrayResult1, array1);
        int[] array2 = {100, 200, 3, 10};
        firstSteps.cube(array2);
        int[] arrayResult2 = {1000000, 8000000, 27, 1000};
        assertArrayEquals(arrayResult2, array2);
}
```

My code is like that`public void cube(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
            int result = (int)Math.pow(i,3);
        }`

The test is failed with the result 2 instead of 8. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @user207421 yeah but it's just for the sake of learning. Everyone of us did simple things and mistakes at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, and every one of us has to learn from what we are told. No exception here. It is pointless trying to test methods that don't do anything observable. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 even though the question isn't a quality one, I feel it deserves an answer, which might be helpful for OP.

Comment: @LppEdd It deserves an answer that says the method is untestable as posted, and that has already been stated.

Comment: @user207421 she will realize that with time. It's not useful here to just write "unstestable and pointless" imho.

Comment: @user207421 You're right. But I think in the end you got what I'm trying to say. Anyway I appreciate a positive confrontation, so that's fine.

Comment: @LppEdd Csrtainly not. I have *refuted* what you're trying to say. You have specifically accused me of 'just' writing 'untestable and pointless', and that is simply untrue. I provided cogent reasons for what I wrote, and you have just wilfully ignored them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple here (don't be scared of the long answer, it's interesting!)

```
firstSteps.cube(array1);
```

You're passing an array instance to the `cube` method, that's fine. However

```
public void cube(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        int result = (int)Math.pow(i,3);
    }
}
```

You're not touching the input array, you're not even using it. See

```
(int)Math.pow(i,3);
```

You're passing the counter variable `i` to the `pow` method instead of `array[i]`.
Also, you're assigning the `pow` result to a limited scope local variable, which means the `result` variable will continually be re-created with a new initial value but no real usefulness.

Another problem is here

```
i <= array.length
```

This will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, as you'll lookup an index greater than the one available in `array`. Remember that indexes starts at `0`!

What you can do, for example, is assign the `Math.pow` result to the original array

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (int) Math.pow(array[i], 3);
}
```

Because as you know, arrays are passed by refence, and the elements inside it will be updated for everyone having a reference to it.

Now, this

```
int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 0};
firstSteps.cube(array1);
int[] arrayResult1 = {1, 8, 27, 0};
assertArrayEquals(arrayResult1, array1);
```

will work : )

---

Olivier Grégoire suggested in the comments to add an intermediate step between modifying the input array (which is what you're doing now, and which is usually **not a good choice** as it can lead to unexpected side effects) and using the `Stream` library. See comments, and remember the logic is the same as using the `Stream` solution below, just not in a functional manner.

```
public int[] cube(final int[] array) {
    // Initialize a new array, with the same size as the input one,
    // to hold the computed value. We will return this array instead
    // of modifying the inputted one. 
    final int[] powResult = new int[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        powResult[i] = (int) Math.pow(array[i], 3);
    }

    return powResult;
}
```

You can now use this as

```
// We use array1 only as input
final int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 0};
final int[] powResult = firstSteps.cube(array1);
int[] arrayResult1 = {1, 8, 27, 0};

// We use the returned powResult for comparison,
// as array1 has not been touched.
assertArrayEquals(arrayResult1, powResult);
```

---

As an addition, I'd like to introduce you a version using a *functional* approach.

```
public int[] cube(final int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array)
                    .map(v -> (int) Math.pow(v, 3))
                    .toArray();
}
```

Here we do not touch the `array` input array, but we create a new, modified copy, using a `Stream`. That is the array becomes an `int` flow, and we can examine each element of that flow.

```
.map(v -> (int) Math.pow(v, 3))
```

If you keep programming you'll probably arrive to the conclusion that this solution is a lot better.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Got it and that worked for me! And such a silly mistake with <= thing.

Comment: @MariiaPalyga That's fine! Learn from your mistakes ;)

Comment: @MariiaPalyga btw, I suggest you read these two articles to better understand how the community works. They'll help you in the long term here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think that the experience of the OP with programming is too low to start using what you call the functional approach. You could probably add an intermediate step between the "modify the input array" and the "functional approach" where you create an new array and write all the cubes in the new array.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thank you for the edit Olivier. Yes, you're right. I will add an intermediate step to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You  have  too  many  bugs!  So I try to rebuild those code.

- You  class  shuold  looks  like  this:
  -

package com.lee.test;

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   public class FirstSteps {
      List<Integer> resultArray = new ArrayList<>();
    public int[] cube(int[]array) {
        for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
            int result = (int)Math.pow(array[i], 3);
            resultArray.add(result);
        }
        Integer[] array01 = resultArray.toArray(new Integer[resultArray.size()]);
        int [] array02 = new int[array01.length];
        for(int j = 0;j<array01.length;j++) {
            array02[j] = array01[j];
        }
        for(int k:array02) {
            System.out.println(k);
        }
        return array02;

    }
   }
```

2.Then your  test  code should  looks  like this:

```
package com.lee.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

import org.junit.Test;


public class TestFirstSteps {
    @Test
    public void testCubeArray() {

        FirstSteps firstSteps1 = new FirstSteps();
        int[] array1 = {1,2,3,0};
        int[] guessResult01 = firstSteps1.cube(array1);
        int []arrayResult = {1,8,27,0};
        assertArrayEquals(arrayResult, guessResult01);

        FirstSteps firstSteps2 = new FirstSteps();
        int[] array2 = {100,200,3,10};
        int[] guessResult02 = firstSteps2.cube(array2);
        int[] arrayResult2 = {1000000,8000000,27,1000};
        assertArrayEquals(guessResult02, arrayResult2);
        }

}
```

3.The  problems  with  your  code!

- no  return  value with your method,So  there  is  no param to  passed to  junit.
- you shuold not use one  object test two array,it means you shuold init twice
  FirstSteps  object  to  use!
- Wish  You  a  have  a  happy  program life!

Comment: Your class is so full of side effects which will lead to bugs... There's no reason at all to keep a list. Why not simply create a new array with the same length as the original, and write cubes in it directly? Why do you have to make so many intermediate copies?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks for remind,I just think a list can  avoid the  the bound out of array Exception.But here,we konw the  length of  array firstly,we actualy can simply use a array,thanks for your  advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs here. First one, neither you create any array in `cube` method, that you can return and work with nor change the existing one. Rewrite the body of `cube` method as follows:

```
public void cube(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) Math.pow(array[i], 3);
    }
}
```

Now the tests should pass as follows:

```
int[] array2 = {100, 200, 3, 10};
firstSteps.cube(array2);
int[] expected = {1000000, 8000000, 27, 1000};
assertArrayEquals(expected, array2);
```

Analogously should be done with other assertions in your test.

Comment: He *is* creating an array.

Comment: There is nothing about 'in cube method' in your answer or my comment.

Comment: You stated, and I quote, 'you are not creating any array'. He is. As follows: `int[] array1 = ...`. QED. And in fact he is also creating *three other* arrays ... Four arrays is rather different from none.

Comment: Which colon, after what, and what exactly would whichever colon you mean be supposed to signify? Please try to write intelligibly.

Comment: After the sentence I cited there is some code. It is not a method body. It is just two lines of code that could belong anywhere. They doesn't make the sentence correct. It isn't. The OP is creating not zero, or one, but *four*arrays, contrary to your specific assertion. You have entirely failed to make it clear what on earth you're talking about, if you want to 'provide useful content' here you need to start by expressing yourself clearly.

Comment: And now your suggested method completely ignore the input array. There is no evidence here that you've even understood the question, let alone answered it. It is clear from the OP's code that he is expecting to cube the elements of the input array.

Comment: @user207421 I'm sorry man, you're perfectly right, something must be wrong with my head, I've tried again, thank you for your time!